# Collectionviewcell autolayout height, dynamic height, height to content

Tags: swift, dynamic, uicollectionview, height, uicollectionviewcell

Been searching for hours trying to find an answer to this!

I need my collectionviewcells height to resize after the size of the content inside the cell. Anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks, Lloyd

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to resize the height of UICollectionViewCell after the content size inside the cell is changed. You can just set the custom height for the cell, and set the certain auto layout constraints to the objects inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection view delegate should implement method `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, where you can calculate size for your cell manually or by using method `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)`.